# What is difference between session.getBasicRemote().sendText() and session.getAsyncRemote().sendText() in websockets api

Tags: java

I'm beginner of java websockets api.

What is difference between session.getBasicRemote().sendText() and session.getAsyncRemote().sendText() in websockets api

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello");
```

and

```
session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation, let's take a look at undertow.

getBasicRemote() eventually calls WebSockets.sendBlockingInternal(...), which waits for the buffer to be flushed:

```
private static void sendBlockingInternal(final PooledByteBuffer pooledData, WebSocketFrameType type, final WebSocketChannel wsChannel) throws IOException {
    boolean closePooledData = true;
    try {
        StreamSinkFrameChannel channel = wsChannel.send(type);
        // TODO chunk data into some MTU-like thing to control packet size
        closePooledData = false; // channel.send takes ownership of pooledData so it no longer needs to be closed
        if(!channel.send(pooledData)) {
            throw WebSocketMessages.MESSAGES.unableToSendOnNewChannel();
        }
        channel.shutdownWrites();
        while (!channel.flush()) {
            channel.awaitWritable();
        }
        if (type == WebSocketFrameType.CLOSE && wsChannel.isCloseFrameReceived()) {
            IoUtils.safeClose(wsChannel);
        }
    } finally {
        if (closePooledData) {
            pooledData.close();
        }
    }
}
```

getAsyncRemote() calls WebSockets.sendInternal(...) which flushes asynchronously, and regsiters a Future(callback) which is called when it's done.

```
private static <T> void sendInternal(final PooledByteBuffer pooledData, WebSocketFrameType type, final WebSocketChannel wsChannel, final WebSocketCallback<T> callback, T context, long timeoutmillis) {
    boolean closePooledData = true;
    try {
        StreamSinkFrameChannel channel = wsChannel.send(type);
        // TODO chunk data into some MTU-like thing to control packet size
        closePooledData = false; // channel.send takes ownership of pooledData so it no longer needs to be closed
        if(!channel.send(pooledData)) {
            throw WebSocketMessages.MESSAGES.unableToSendOnNewChannel();
        }
        flushChannelAsync(wsChannel, callback, channel, context, timeoutmillis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onError(wsChannel, context, e);
        } else {
            IoUtils.safeClose(wsChannel);
        }
    } finally {
        if ( closePooledData ) {
            pooledData.close();
        }
    }
}
```

So the difference is, the sync version has to wait for the channel to be writable, and return after the channel is written.

Answer (score 0):

With [getBasicRemote()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.Basic.html) your messages are sent Synchronously.

With [getAsyncRemote()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.Async.html) your messages are sent Asynchronously.